# python3 why is a 'string' not a str?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need this little snippet to output "this is a string" (i need myVar to satisfy the condition is str)

```
myVar = 'some-string'
if myVar is str:
    print('this is a string')
else:
    print('this is NOT a string')
```

but when i run it, it keeps outputting "this is NOT a string".
I don't understand, can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

I've also tried:

```
myVar = str('some-string')
if myVar is str:
    print('this is a string')
else:
    print('this is NOT a string')
```

and it also doesn't work.

I can't use isinstance() to check anything, I MUST keep the conditional of

```
if myVar is str:
```

and this conditional must evaluate to True.

i've also tried this:

```
if 'some-string' is str:
    print('this is a string')
else:
    print('this is NOT a string')
```

and this also outputs "this is NOT a string"

I don't know what i need to do to feed it something which satisfies this condition

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) to understand what `is` does.

Comment: *"I can't use isinstance() to check anything, I MUST keep the conditional"* That's unfortunate. You'll have to rewrite the python interpreter if you want that to work. Good luck.

Comment: Please mark one of the solutions as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

```
if type(myVar) is str:
```

and

```
if isinstance(myVar, str):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check is incorrect, `str` is an object of class `type` which can create instances of `class str` the correct check is:

```
myVar = str('some-string')
if isinstance(myVar,str):
    print('this is a string')
else:
    print('this is NOT a string')
```

The same way given `class A` this check:

`if x is A` is incorrect

Defining a class creates a special object of class `type` that is responsible for creating  instances of the defined class that is why you need to use `isinstace()` or `issubclass()` which uses this special object and the object given to answer the query. Because simple `is` checks if object x is object A and that is not true.

Comment: when i try your code, it does indeed output 'this is a string', thank you! I will try to correct my situation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an object is a string (or any type for that matter) use `isinstance(Myvar, str)` which will be True if Myvar is string.

So:

```
myvar = 'this is a string'
if isinstance(myvar, str):
    print(f'the variable {myvar} is a string')
else:
    print(f'the variable {myvar} is not a string')
```

To be pythonic do not use capitals for variables...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = "Hello"
>>> isinstance(string,str)
True
>>> isinstance(1,str)
False
>>> if isinstance(string,str):
    print("this is a string")
else:
    print("this is not a string")

this is a string
>>>
```